Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". when upgrade react pdf to 9.x
Today when I upgrade the react-pdf https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf version to 9.1.0, the pdf load failed and shows error:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I have tried to upgrade the pdfjs version to 4.4.168 but still could not fixed this issue. Does anyone facing the same issue? This is the pdfjs code:
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `/pdfjs-dist/4.4.168/pdf.worker.min.mjs`;

this version works fine in the local machine. But failed when I publish it to production environment. I have check the pdfjs build folder and there is only contains file with mjs extension. I check the browser response and found the mjs file type is application/octet-stream, then I tried to change the mine type configuration in openresty:
application/javascript                           js mjs;

still did not fixed this issue. I found the local content-type return application/javascript that works fine.

I have tried to remove the leading / but still did not fixed this issue.

it looks like thie chrome could not handle mjs file, or the response mine type are not  correct. it works fine with the local machine run in localhost.

Did you manage to solve this?

yes, I have resolved it by tweak the nginx mine type. @İbrahimAkar

This issue was that the 9.1.0 react-pdf upgrade the pdfjs to the new version which using mjs by default. To make the nginx support mjs, we should add the config with nginx:
types {
      application/javascript js mjs;
  }

for more information: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/20157. Also we can downgrade the version to legacy one, but I still prefer to use the newest version with mjs support.
